# Drupal 7 - Main Content Pushed Down by Sidebar Content

Tags: html, css, drupal, web, sidebar

I am difficulty working out an issue with Drupal 7 and IE / non - IE browsers. I built my own template using php, html, and css. I also have some custom javascript content.

As is, my website has a couple of notable differences between IE and non-IE browsers that I am looking for solutions to. The main issue I have is that in browsers that are not IE, all blocks of information within the main content region are being pushed downwards past my sidebar (except for the first block, which is somehow unaffected). I noticed this is NOT the case in IE. I would like to fix it so that the positioning of the content in the main div is not at all affected by the content in the sidebar.

Also if anyone has some tips on fixing my slider for cross-browser compatibility (because it is currently being butchered by IE) that would be much appreciated. The shadows don't work in IE, the transparent black background doesn't work, and the entire slider moves very slowly and jaggedly.

You can find my site here:

http://preview.iss.wisc.edu

Thanks,

Nick Vander Woude

Tech Assistant / Web Designer

International Student Services at UW Madison

Comment: that link is not working

Comment: link should work now... I forgot to omit the 'www.'

Comment: you can throw a height of 200px on #node-8 and it brings up the content. In IE, there is an error being thrown on the javascript slider... line 5... check the order of the scripts being loaded in your .info file of your theme. Make sure jquery is loaded first

Comment: since IE7 seems to be working correctly, you might check what rules you have used for IE and if you've had to use IE7 specific, either use a conditional statement or the * hack to keep IE+ from being affected. That height is hard to track down

Comment: I'll check the .info file and try to figure out if that's the cause of the issue with the slider. I don't have browser specific styles yet, and although I'd rather avoid that, I would be willing to implement it if it could solve my problem. Although I have to say I'm not quite sure how to do that in Drupal 7...

The height issue is still bothering me though. Especially because the issue never appears on IE but persists on all other browsers.

Comment: IE 7 works, but IE 8 does not as well as Firefox, Safari and Chrome. But, adding the height of 200px to #node-8 will fix that for the other, lions share of browsers. Just put a css file together, put it in the css folder in your theme folder and add the css file into your .info file for the theme. Be sure to clear your theme cache.

Comment: That won't work, sorry. It's a site-wide issue. I can't simply add styling to #node-8 because the issue is only with #node-8 in one specific place with one specific configuration. Check out other pages on the site, you'll see what I mean. For example: http://preview.iss.wisc.edu/newsletters/access-iss , as well as: http://preview.iss.wisc.edu/announcements

Comment: After a bit more investigation I have discovered the issue is almost certainly directly related to the 'node' class. What is happening is that the first node which appears is given a height equal to that of the sidebar height. Why this is happening, however, I am not sure. I've tried using the style:

#content-area .node {
height: auto;
}

But to no avail. Any Drupal experts out there to help?

Comment: Have you installed the Theme Developer module? Install that, visit a page then click the little box at the lower left that will appear. Then, wherever you click on your page, you

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer ? If so, I can already use Google Chrome's "Inspect element" option, so I don't need firebug or a firebug module to understand what's happening on my page. Unless there's something specific you're thinking it could help me discover that I don't already know...

Comment: yes, but that's for Drupal. Installed, it will give you a block to click on the lower left. Then, wherever you click on a page, it will tell you what template, functions etc Drupal is using to render the content. That can help track down where the node class or other calls may be to edit

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try. At this point I don't have a lot to lose.

Comment: I tried adding "overflow: hidden" to the .node class, it's seemed to have worked. I just want to be sure that there's no negative side effects somewhere else because of this.

Comment: a test would be to just copy a paragraph and paste it a couple of times to make sure that area with the .node class grows. If it gets cut-off, change it to overflow:auto. You might have to look around elsewhere to be sure you avoid scrollbars. Seems like this is all a css issue in the theme.